# Django admin: how to format readonly fields?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

I have a model, `Director` with two DateFields, and two subclasses (code below). I am trying to create an admin page for each Director which shows the corresponding subclass instance, and not the `Director` instance; this part is mostly easy (I create an inline for each subclass, give the main ModelAdmin a form with all fields excluded, and have the main ModelAdmin only request formsets from the inlines which have a corresponding instance - the code; there is an unresolved issue with this approach, which I note below, but is not the focus of this question).

**The problem I have is that I want to massage the values displayed to the user, one of which is shown in a readonly field, one of which is not. The processing is that I want to change a magic value (`date(1,1,1)`) to the string `"On incorporation"`.**

Dates in readonly fields aren't rendered in a format very friendly to parsing, and I would like to reduce unnecessary dependence on javascript, so I would very much prefer a server-side solution.

The code below displays the forms as I want them, except that date values are not massaged at all, and when saving, there is a spurious "Please correct the error below" message, even though there are no errors, and all fields are saved correctly.

**My question is: how do I intercept the values to be rendered on the page, both in readonly fields, and in forms fields, and alter them to display a string of my choosing?**

The models (so far as material):

```
class Director(models.Model, Specializable):
    date_of_appointment = models.DateField()
    date_ceased_to_act = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)

class DirectorsIndividual(Director):
     pass

class DirectorsCorporate(Director):
     pass
```

The admin code:

```
class DirectorAdmin(EnhancedAdmin):

    fields = ()

##    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
##        return None

    def queryset(self, request):
        """ Directors for all companies which are incorporated by the current user's organisation """
        individual = Individual.for_user(request.user)
        return Director.objects.filter(company__incorporation_ticket__ordered_by__in = Organisation.all_organisations_for_which_individual_authorised_to_incorporate(individual))

    class form(forms.ModelForm):
        # have this return no html - that way only inlines are shown
        class Meta:
            fields = ()
            pass

        def is_valid(self):
            self._errors = {}
            return True

    class DirectorsIndividualInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = DirectorsIndividual
        fk_name = 'director_ptr'
        extra = 0
        readonly_fields = ('deferred_on','company','date_of_appointment',)
        can_delete = False

        def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
            if obj and obj.company and not obj.company.is_submitted(): return self.readonly_fields # allow editing of fields listed in else
            else:
                return itertools.chain(self.readonly_fields, ('individual', 'is_secretary'))

        def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
            return obj and ((obj.company and not obj.company.is_submitted()) or not obj.company)

        class form(forms.ModelForm):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields['surrogate_for'].required = False
                self.fields['representative_for'].required = False
                if self.instance:
                    obj = self.instance
                    for field in (f for f in type(obj)._meta.fields if type(f) == fields.DateField):
                        val = field.value_from_object(obj)
                        assert (type(val) in (datetime.date, type(None),))
                        # assert field.name != 'date_of_appointment'
                        if val == inc_consts.EARLIEST_DATE:
                            self.initial[field.name] = "On incorporation"

            def is_valid(self):
                self._errors = {}
                return True

    class DirectorsCorporateInline(admin.StackedInline):

        model = DirectorsCorporate
        fk_name = 'director_ptr'
        extra = 0
        can_delete = False

        class form(forms.ModelForm):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                if True:
                    for k in self.fields:
                        self.fields[k].required = False

            def is_valid(self):
                self._errors = {}
                return True


    inlines = (DirectorsIndividualInline,DirectorsCorporateInline)

    def get_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
        return (inline for inline in (self.inline_instances)
                if inline.model.objects.filter(**{(inline.fk_name or self.model._meta.object_name.lower()) : obj }))

    def get_formsets(self, request, obj=None):
        """ only return formset for inlines for which there exists an object """
        return (inline.get_formset(request, obj) for inline in self.get_inlines(request, obj))
```

I realise that there is an asymmetry between `DirectorsCorporateInline` and `DirectorsIndividualInline`; that is because I am testing on an instance with a `DirectorsIndividual` instance. The code above refers to model fields not shown in the models, because they are not material to the dates issue; it should be possible to render them immaterial for the spurious error issue without altering those fields (although I realise it is less helpful for that issue, I want to keep this question mostly focused on one issue). `EnhancedAdmin` is a `ModelAdmin` subclass with some minor alterations which shouldn't be of consequence. Extra code can be shown on reasoned request, but I don't want to confuse with irrelevant code.

For completeness: I am using django 1.3.1 on python 2.7.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a member function of your `Director` class that renders the readonly_field as you want.

```
class Director(models.Model, Specializable):
    date_of_appointment = models.DateField()
    date_ceased_to_act = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    def date_of_appointment_str(self):
        if self.date_of_appointment == datetime.date(1,1,1):
            return "On incorporation"
        else:
            return "%s" % (self.date_of_appointment) # format as you wish
```

and then just add `'date_of_appointment_str'` to your list of `readonly_fields` in the admin.

EDIT: I should add that this is one quick solution.  A more robust solution is to subclass `models.DateField` into a `MyCustomDateField` that acts like a `DateField` except that when the value is `date(1,1,1)` it renders as "On incorporation" or when a user saves "On incorporation" it saves the value as `date(1,1,1)`.  This would ensure that you can reuse this functionality everywhere this field type shows up.  However, if it only shows up in one place; this may be overkill.

You'd need something like (this is untested; you may need to additionally alter your the forms `DateField` and/or other things; e.g., if you use django-south you'll have to add custom introspection rules).

```
class MyCustomDateField(models.DateField):
    date_111_str = 'On incorporation'
    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        val = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        if val is None:
            data = ''
        elif val.year == val.day == val.month == 1:
            data = date_111_str
        else:
            data = datetime_safe.new_date(val).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        return data
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value == date_111_str:
            value = datetime.date(1,1,1)
        return super(MyCustomDateField,self).get_prep_value(self, value)
```

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to do it by defining a custom callback in the `ModelAdmin`.  Let's say the field is called `my_datetime`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.formats import localize


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('my_datetime_localized',)

    def my_datetime_localized(self, obj):
        return localize(obj.my_datetime)
    my_datetime_localized.short_description = 'Date / time'
```

Note: if `settings.USE_L10N` is `True`, this will display the datetime in the local time of the viewer, which is probably what you want.  If you want to keep `USE_L10N` as `False` then you can override its behaviour like so: `return localize(obj.my_datetime, use_l10n=True)`.

Answer (score 2):

As @drjimbob (and carljm on #django) suggested, the solution is to create a member function or property on the model, e.g.:

```
class Director(models.Model, Specializable):
    date_of_appointment = models.DateField()
    date_ceased_to_act = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)

    #def date_formatter and def _date_format_factory omitted

    date_of_appointment_formatted = lambda self: self.date_formatter(getattr(self, 'date_of_appointment'))
    date_ceased_to_act_formatted = _date_format_factory(None, 'date_ceased_to_act') #for some reason, I get a 'classmethod/staticmethod object is not callable' error if I decorate _date_format_factory
    date_of_appointment_formatted.short_description = u'Date of appointment'
```

Note the `date_of_appointment_formatted.short_description` - the `ModelAdmin` will use the `short_description` as the label for a `readonly_field`.

To get the properties working with model fields, a custom form is needed:

```
class DirectorInlineForm(EnhancedModelForm):
    from django.utils import formats
    date_ceased_to_act_formatted = forms.DateField(required = False, widget = admin.widgets.AdminDateWidget,
                                                   label = u'Date officer\'s appointment terminated',
                                                   input_formats = formats.get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS') + (Director.on_incorporation,))

            class Meta:
                model = Director # Note that model declaration is necessary for this to work with additional fields declared


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DirectorInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # set initial values from model of declared fields
        if self.instance:
            self.initial['date_ceased_to_act_formatted'] = self.instance.date_ceased_to_act_formatted


    def save(self, commit = True):
        # save logic for magic formatted fields
        if self._raw_value('date_ceased_to_act_formatted') == Director.on_incorporation:
            sval = Director.on_incorporation
        else: sval = self.cleaned_data['date_ceased_to_act_formatted']

        self.instance.date_ceased_to_act_formatted = sval

        return super(forms.ModelForm, self).save(commit)
```

The `ModelForm` needs a custom field to display the property; a custom `__init__` to set the initial value for the field from the property, and a custom save, to set the model property from the form field.

In my example, the save also has to be aware of the magic value, because of how `DateField` handles the magic value. You could push that code into a custom field instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would massage field values with javascript. You can [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) the admin templates, and attach your javascript code into the `{% block extrahead %}` block ( some more info from the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter17/)). Put your magic massage function example into `.ready()` (if you use jQuery).

I hope this will work for you, because I would like to do something similar, but haven't implemented yet. :)

Comment: They aren't really rendered consistently, which will make using javascript a pain; I will probably have to, so thanks for the info.