# How do I right-align read-only fields in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to right align numeric fields in the admin interface of my Django app. For "normal" editable fields this works ok by overriding `formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):` for the `ModelAdmin` class:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
    field = super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
    if db_field.name in ("total_amount", "total_discount_amount"):
        field.widget.attrs['style'] = 'text-align:right;'
    return field
```

When a field is defined as a read-only field, it by passes this method and gets rendered in a different way (apparently just as a css styled paragraph tag).

Is there a way to right align a read-only field? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706408/django-admin-how-to-format-readonly-fields) on SO but its problem is a different one from mine, I think...

Comment: have you found a solution for your issue?

Comment: @nemesisdesign: Yes, I solved it by "bootstrapping" the admin and use their readonly inputs which is basically what you suggested. I have accepted your answer although a bit late...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use css? Define a an /admin/base.html template in which you load a custom css that specifies:

```
input[readonly="readonly"]{
    text-align: right
}
```

If you need to restrict the styiling of certain readonly fields you could still use css by doing something like:

```
#my-app fieldset input[readonly="readonly"]{
    text-align: right
}
```

or even specific fields:

```
#id_total, #id_average, #id_my_readonly_field{
    text-align: right
}
```

## Addendum

I see you are using Grappelli, in that case you could do:

```
.grp-readonly{
    float: right;
}
```

If you need to style only certain readonly paragraphs and not all of them you could still prefix the CSS rule with the css class of the parent element, usually the class is named after the field name, so if you have a file called "total" it would be:

```
.total .grp-readonly{
    float: right;
}
```

I think writing a custom filter for a presentation issue is a mantainance overkill that you might regret in the future, are you sure that's the best way to do it?

Comment: Thanks. I had considered that but read only fields are generated as styled paragraphs, not as html input fields. They also do not have an HTML id set so AFAIK there's no option to style them but through the associated class which would then set all read only fields right aligned...

Comment: i added a few more considerations